# SQL Microsoft Report Builder millisecond events are not retrieved

Tags: sql, database, reporting-services

I get my data from a data base by following query:

```
SELECT      TemperatureSensor3.Timestamp, 
        TemperatureSensor3.CurrentTemperature AS CurrentTemperature_3, 
        TemperatureSensor4.CurrentTemperature AS CurrentTemperature_4 

FROM        TemperatureSensor4

LEFT JOIN   TemperatureSensor3 

ON          TemperatureSensor4.Timestamp = TemperatureSensor3.Timestamp


WHERE       TemperatureSensor3.Timestamp >= '2020-01-17 12:00:00.000' AND 
        TemperatureSensor3.Timestamp <='2020-01-17 18:00:00.000'
AND         TemperatureSensor4.Timestamp >= '2020-01-17 12:00:00.000' AND 
        TemperatureSensor4.Timestamp <='2020-01-17 18:00:00.000'

ORDER BY    TemperatureSensor3.Timestamp
```

Problem is that only the data that has a whole second time stamp is retreived.
e.g. 12:15:01.000 is retreived and 12:15:01.567 is not retreived, so that of 1000 entries not all will be retrieved.

I would appreciate any suggestion how to deal with this,
Thanks
Drazen

Comment: Sample data would help. Also note your `left` join is effectively inner as  `TemperatureSensor3.Timestamp >= ..  and  `TemperatureSensor3.Timestamp <= ..` exclude NULLs

Comment: Thanks @Serg for the quick reply. I have overlooked the fact that Timestamp has to be exactly the same for the entries in both tables if I want to join the columns. I guess it does vary in miliseconds.